# django models Values error preventing me from creating a model with fields specified as parameters?e

Tags: python, django, django-models, models

I don't seem to understand this error or how to fix it. There's something I don't understand about django models.

Consider what happens when I try to perform `get_or_create` on the `Keyword` model. Here's the model, alongside some code I write in shell.

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Keyword(models.Model):
    word      = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    statement = models.ManyToManyField(Statement)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.word


>>> from gtr_site.models import *
>>> a = Statement()
>>> Keyword.objects.get_or_create(word="Testkeyword", statement=a)
Traceback (most recent call last): ...
ValueError: "<Keyword: Testkeyword>" needs to have a value for field "keyword" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

**But if you simply write** `Keyword.objects.get_or_create(word="TestKeyWord")` (so if you exclude the statement instance entirely), then the error disappears.

I really don't understand how this error can be occurring because... Neither the `Statement` model nor the `Keyword` model actually have a field called "keyword."

However, the `Statement` model does have a lot of components. Here's the code for it.

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Statement(models.Model):
    statement_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    issue_date = models.DateField("Issue-Date")
    author = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    released_by = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField('KeywordInContext')
    solokeywords = models.ManyToManyField('Keyword', related_name='statement_keywords')
```

There's three more choice fields in the model that I chose to exclude for the sake of clarity.

There's only one field in the `Statements` model that actually *does have* a field called keyword. The field "keywords" which creates a ManyToMany relationship with `KeywordInContext` This model is as follows:

```
 @python_2_unicode_compatible
 class KeywordInContext(models.Model):
    keyword = models.ForeignKey(Keyword)
    contexts = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword, related_name='keyword_context')

 def __str__(self):
    return self.keyword.word + ' (' + ', '.join(c.word for c in self.contexts.all()) + ')'
```

Important to note is that the field keyword makes a ForeignKey to a `Keyword` object.

So... I still don't understand how this is happening. When I am trying to create  new Keyword that has both of its `word` and `statement` field's as parameters, I don't understand why a field from KeyInContext even becomes relevant. With respect to that, how do I create a `Keyword` object with both of its `word` and `statement` parameters specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is trying to tell you that you need to save the Keyword object before you can link to it via a many-to-many. You will also need to save the Statement; this is because an m2m relationship involves a linking table, so both sides need IDs before you can link them. In other words, you can't assign an m2m field in the `create` call.

As to why you get that particular message, I guess you have an old version of the models in memory where you defined the primary key field as `keyword`.

Comment: Hi. I started doing some testing that actually was suggesting exactly what you said. but .save() isn't working quite in context.

I perform `Statement.objects.update_or_create()` (albeit currently, I don't save the instance upon update or creation). 

Then what follows is I get the Statement object that was just updated or created.  `cur_statement = Statement.objects.get_or_create(statement_id = statement["statement_id"])`

But if I try to save it... `cur_statement.save()` gives error `'tuple' object has no attribute 'save'`

Comment: Nevermind. I made it work exactly as desired. I will go provide an answer with the code that I used (or to summarize basically)

Comment: Dumb error on my part. Spent a day not realizing you can't assign m2m objects in a create call.